# Rss feed in webview in android

Tags: android

I want to show rss feeds of link http://dekora.com/blog/?feed=rss2. I have done it successfully and i am showing it in a list view. But i have one problem in i want to display the element of  tag, but here lits of HTML tags are coming. So what should i do for this? Should i replace all the HTML tags or there is any Convenient way to display this tag element. Can i show this tag element in a webview? In iPhone if we put this tag element in webview it shows the things in a good and convenient way. Can any body help?

Comment: in this question i wan to display the element of content tag that i have missed to mention in question

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? You can post an answer to your self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display HTML you can look into [android.text.Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html).

You will need to use a custom adapter so you can control the display of the list view, so when you output the content you can do something like:

```
lblRSSContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(rssItem.getContent()));
```

I've noticed that the rss feed you provided also contains images. So you should also look into [Html.ImageGetter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html) so you can process and display the images.